# How to script a SQL "between" that does not include the same day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date, logic, between

I am looking to retrieve all records which `myDate` is between the `startDate` and 'endDate', but do not return records with exactly the same date. I am using MS SQL 2005.

I have tried:

`Select *`
`From myDatabase`
`Where empId = 145`
`and myDate between startDate and endDate`

But if myDate was '11/16/2011' the above query would return records which have a `startDate` and `endDate` = '11/16/2011' as well. This isn't what I want. I do not want records which have a `startDate` and `endDate` = `myDate`

So I tried:

`Select *`
`From myDatabase`
`Where empId = 145`
`and myDate between startDate and endDate`
`and (myDate <> startDate AND myDate <> endDate)`

Will this work for all cases?

Comment: Do you want to include records where myDate can be either, but not both, startDate and endDate?

Comment: I would like to exclude records where myDate is either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a1ex07 is right in that this will work

`myDate > startDate AND myDate < endDate`

If you insist on using `BETWEEN` then this will work also

<s>`mydate BETWEEN startDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND endDate - INTERVAL 1 DAY`</s>

**Edit**: Just saw the tags for SQL Server not MySQL so the above is for MySQL, the SQL Server equivalent is

`myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, startDate) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, endDate)`

Comment: Note that your solutions aren't really equivalent as soon as time is in the equation (which is always the case with SQL Server 2005, since pure `date` type was introduced in version 2008).

Comment: @Lucero not sure I follow what your getting at in your comment?  If time is in the date it simple remains the same. `DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2011-11-18 05:00:00') = 2011-11-19 05:00:00` and `'2011-11-18 05:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY = 2011-11-19 05:00:00`

Comment: Thank you, I am making sure to set all time to 00:00:00.00

Comment: @Lucero NM Lucero I got what your saying after thinking it over, since he just doesn't want to include dates equal to myDate then if the date was `2011-11-18 05:00:00` and you just add +1 day to get `2011-11-19 05:00:00` then you're missing out on all the records from `2011-11-19 00:00:00` to `2011-11-19 04:59:59`.  This applies to using > and < also, so technically all of our solutions wont work exactly if time is involved. +1 to you for that observation.

Comment: @JeffWilbert, exactly, that's what I was referring to. But dates with time components are dangerous beasts anyways... if you're not careful you can get in trouble due to time zones, DST changes or other issues related to not using UTC everywhere. But that doesn't really make any of the solutions here better or worse, it's just an observation and hint/warning for CodingIsAwesome. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you have to use `BETWEEN`... Just `myDate>startDate AND myDate<endDate` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to include records where myDate can be either, but not both, startDate and endDate, this should work:

```
Select *
From myDatabase
Where empId = 145
and myDate between startDate and endDate
and startDate <> endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something other than `BETWEEN`. Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM myDatabase
WHERE empID = 145
AND (myDate > startDate) and (myDate < endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN` uses `>=` and `<=`

You will just need to use `>` and `<` if you don't want it to match the end points.

```
SELECT *
FROM myDatabase
WHERE empId = 145
AND myDate>startDate and myDate<startDate;
```